# Ember - advanced routing structure for user impersonation

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

In my app I have the following user hierarchy `organisation (org) > reseller > customer`. From a business perspective all three user types in the hierarchy are a customer with a `:customer_id`. From an app perspective they are seperate concerns, with the ability to impersonate users down the hierarchy.

So their base URL would all be the equivalent of:

`localhost/org/:customer_id.`

But An organisation could route into a reseller as:

`localhost/org/:customer_id/reseller/:customer_id.`

And both organisation and resellers could route into customers as:

`localhost/org/:customer_id/reseller/:customer_id/customer/:customer_id` 
or
`localhost/reseller/:customer_id/customer/:customer_id`

#### Problems with this structure

The main issue is that every customer has it's own site and service route. And I want to avoid repeating routes under the top level `:customer_id`. Essentially ending up with the following.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('org', { path: 'org/:customer_id' }, function() {
    this.route('site');
    this.route('service');
    this.route('reseller', { path: 'reseller/:customer_id' }, function() {
      this.route('site');
      this.route('service');
      this.route('customer', { path: 'customer/:customer_id' }, function() {
        this.route('site');
        this.route('service');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But I'm unsure how to split the routes so that they inherit the correct URL structure but aren't nested. And in a way where each customer can access/impersonate at the correct level.

#### As an aside

If I can't figure out how to execute this I'm planning on using a user-service to set a currentUser variable for impersonation, and then stripping the URL to `localhost/org/:org_id/` for every customer. But this won't reflect the level of impersonation in the URL.

Comment: You should look into http://ember-engines.com/.

Comment: That looks pretty awesome - cheers @locks